# Internet explorer Dom elements getElementById

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, appendchild

Under Internet Explorer 8, when I try to copy a Div from a window to a pop-up the getElementById method doesn't return DOM elements but plain elements. I can't call appendChild on those sort of items cause I get "Illegal argument" errors. What would be a solution of copying a div from a parrent window to a child pop-up window.

The code I've written so far works perfectly on Chrome, and Firefox, but not on IE.

this code is in the pop-up window:

this is called on when the pop-up is loading

```
<body onload="initialize();">

     <div id='sourceDiv'></div>

</body>

function initialize(){
    var source = window.opener.document; 
    var myDiv = source.getElementById("myDiv"); 
    var destination = document.getElementById("sourceDiv");
    destination.appendChild(myDiv); 
}
```

the following snippet is from the parrent window

```
<div id='myDiv>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do this in jQuery?  jQuery is designed to be browser independent.

jQuery code would be one line like so:

```
$('#sourceDiv').append($('#myDiv').html());
```

Ok I've just tried a test project and this code works:

```
<script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sourceDiv').append($('#myDiv').html());
    });
</script>


<body>
    <div id='sourceDiv'></div>
    <div id="myDiv">myDiv text</div>
</body>
```

You need to make sure the document is loaded when you call your function.

Comment: I have already tried it with jQuery, but I get the same problem. The exception comes in this place from the jQuery library, on the line where it tries to call appendChild on my Div.

Comment: Which code are you using in jQuery?  The code that I posted?  Can you provide a snippet of your html?

Comment: At the moment I'm using the code I posted in the question. I have tried the line you posted and the line without ".html()" - i.e: $('#sourceDiv').append($('#myDiv'). The problem is that sourceDiv doesn't have the javascript method appendChild; jQuery uses appendChild to append my object to the parent DOM element in its implementation.

Comment: I dont understand how a div tag wont have the appendChild method.  Can you provide the snippet of your html that contains your source div?

Comment: The only problem with that code, with your modifications is that the div I'm trying to append is from window.opener.document, i.e. from the the window I opened the pop-up, not from the current window. That works fine, but for my scenario it doesn't.